# How to avoid users to go back to page once login in yii2

Tags: yii2, back-button, yii2-basic-app

I am using yii2 basic application template and hosted filees on my VPS server. In my application login page, when the user logs in successfully to account, he will be able to access the dashboard and all other rights he has been assigned.

Now the scenario is user logs in, then he sees his dashboard as first page. Now if he clicks on back button of the browser error message is displayed as below:

```
This page isn’t working
localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Even if he clicks on back button of the browser he should be redirected to same dashboard page.

How to accomplish this?

Here is my login action:

```
public function actionLogin()
    {
        $this->layout= "loginlayout";
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {

              return $this->redirect("index.php?r=dashboard/index");
            }

        else
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your `login` action?

Comment: You can't disable browser actions (such as going back or closing a tab) in a web app purely server side, there is some JavaScript trickery you can do to achieve this but I wouldn't recommend it

Comment: Does it help if you replace `return $this->goHome()` by `return $this->redirect(['dashboard/index'])`?

Comment: If we click back button first time, second time then it is working fine only dashboard page is redirected. But third time automatic log out, i,e. previous screen is displayed which was before login page.